# vncserver grey screen ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, vnc

Hello so there is lots of discussion about ubuntu 16, and I have tried all of those for 18 but I always get the same grey screen. The relevant part in my perl file is

```
$defaultXStartup
    = ("#!/bin/sh\n\n".
       "# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:\n".
       "# unset SESSION_MANAGER\n".
       "# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc\n\n".
       "[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup\n".
       "[ -r \$HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb \$HOME/.Xresources\n".
       "xsetroot -solid grey\n".
       "vncconfig -iconic &\n".
       "x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title \"\$VNCDESKTOP Desktop\" &\n".
       "x-window-manager &\n".
       "gnome-panel &\n".
       "/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings &\n".
       "metacity &\n".
       "nautilus &\n");
```

No matter what I get the same grey screen. Does anyone have a owrking example of this config for ubuntu 18 ? thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had tried several vnc servers and one automatically created the ~/.vnc/xstartup  so the default in the bin directory was no longer being used and I didn't know it..